# how do i format my nLog layout

Tags: c#, nlog

I have my nLog layout like below

```
  fileTarget.Layout =  "${date}  ${message}";
```

In My code, i am logging like following

```
  logger.Info("ORDER UPDATE",order.Name,order.Instrument,order.OrderState);
```

However it only logs the first string 
for eg.

```
11/22/2012 22:37:16  ORDER UPDATE
11/22/2012 22:37:16  ORDER UPDATE
11/22/2012 22:37:16  ORDER UPDATE
11/22/2012 22:37:16  ORDER UPDATE
```

I am pretty sure that i am missing something in my layout but cannot figure out how to fix it. Can someone point out my error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To save all your strings you should concatenate them first. As I see, your logger recognizes only first one, so you should add other strings you need to make them one string since you are actually logging one string, not several. Or update your logger to recognize numerous strings, I mean something like this: `fileTarget.Layout =  "${date}  ${message1}  ${message2}  ${message3}  ${message4}";`

Comment: The suggestion to concatenate strings is wrong per NLog author: [see "tip" in this section](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Tutorial#emitting-log-messages) -- Try [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15772781/1037948) below

Answer (score 5):

Or you could use the `string.Format` (i.e. `Console.WriteLine`) style expecting token replacement, which is probably what you were intending to use:

```
logger.Info("ORDER UPDATE: Name = {0}; Instrument = {1}; State = {2} ", order.Name, order.Instrument, order.OrderState);
```

rather than assuming the same number of messages for every `Logger` request.

Comment: This is the recommended way to "concatenate" nlog messages due to performance reasons -- [see "tip" in this section of the NLog tutorial](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Tutorial#emitting-log-messages)

Answer (score 0):

Could you do something like:

```
Info("ORDER UPDATE: " + order.Name + ", " + order.Instrument + ", " + order.OrderState);
```